# Visual Studio debugger locking up after access violation in my program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Some invalid code:

```
struct p { int a; int b[3]; }
p* p_object = nullptr;
int v[3]; 
v[0] = p->b[0];
```

The last line triggers a Win32 access violation.  Normally, Visual Studio would interrupt execution, show the spot that violation occurs.

The output window offers:

> Exception thrown at 0x0000000013BDE5D3 (---.dll) in --.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000028.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x00007FF8BBE59D98 in --.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: CSEHException at memory location 0x000000000037D3F8.

Now if I press F5 to continue, **the program locks up,  and the debugger locks up**.  Debug/Stop Debugging hangs Visual Studio.  Eventually a dialog

> "Operation taking longer than expected"

appears.

> A 64 bit debugging operation is taking longer than expected.  This may be caused by incompatibilities with 3rd party networking software."  [Terminate].

I don't have 3rd party networking software.

Terminate stops the debugger, but leaves the program, which can only be killed by Task Manager, which says Not Responding.

Is this behavior expected?  Is something wrong with my debugger?

Comment: Unexpected behavior for unexpected behavior is expected behavior.

Comment: True, but it doesn't usually kill the debugger. All I get from that with MSVC2015 Pro is another "Exception thrown. Break, Continue, Ignore?" prompt whenever I click continue. Mind you I MCVEd it and fixed a couple typos. When asking about stuff like this you need to be really, really precise. Duplicate your code and detail your invocation steps exactly. Even then we might not be able to reproduce, but we have a much better chance of it.

Comment: You'll have to find the evil code that catches this exception.  When you find CSEHException back then you are getting close.